# unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm getting an unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on line 13. I know it seems like quite a complicated set of arrays but it needs yo be like this. There are probably more errors later on also. Please could someone explain my mistake. Thanks

```
<?php

$LibraryStatus = true;
$ControlStatus = true;
$HDDStatus = true;

$arrLayout = array(

         "section1" => array(

         ($LibraryStatus ? array("wLibrary" => array("title"   => "Library",
                                                     "display" => "")) : false),
        ($ControlStatus ? ("wControl" => array("title"   => "Control",
                                                     "display" => "")) : false)),

        "section2" => array(

        ($HDDStatus ? array("whdd" => array("title" => "HDD",
                                            "display" => "")) : false)));
?>
```

Comment: Hooooo boy. Php really needs to be taken out back and shot between the eyeballs.

Answer (score 8):

Missing `array` here:

```
($ControlStatus ? ("wControl" => ...
```

Should be:

```
($ControlStatus ? array("wControl" =>...
```

Comment: Is there any way to write it without having an array there? I need control and library to be part of the array by array("wLibrary".

Comment: It's not possible to use the ternary to control whether a key=>value pair should be included or excluded, but you might be able to use `array_merge` or create unions with `+`

Answer (score 2):

You were missing "array" in one of your conditionals:

```
<?php

$LibraryStatus = true;
$ControlStatus = true;
$HDDStatus = true;

$arrLayout = array(
  "section1" => array(
    ( $LibraryStatus ?
      array(
        "wLibrary" => array(
          "title"   => "Library" ,
          "display" => ""
        )
      ) :
      false ) ,
    ( $ControlStatus ?
      array( /* This was the missing "array" */
        "wControl" => array(
          "title"   => "Control" ,
          "display" => ""
        )
      ) :
      false )
  ) ,
  "section2" => array(
    ( $HDDStatus ?
      array(
        "whdd" => array(
          "title" => "HDD" ,
          "display" => ""
        )
      ) :
      false )
  )
);
?>
```

Comment: @Locanos Is there any way to write it without having an array there? I need control and library to be part of the array by array("wLibrary"

Comment: @Michael: I am not sure I understand what you mean here.

Comment: @Locanos I don't want there to be an array where you saying I left one out. I'm trying to convert this http://codepad.org/1BiYLBhI to have true false options for each one.. It needs to keep its structure.